# Windows server 2008 sp1 x32 bit edition

Tags: windows-server-2008

I was trying to browse the internet for a copy of windows server 2008 service pack 1 32-bit edition I was wondering if this is even a thing and if anyone know where I can get this?

Comment: Might be an X-Y problem -- can you explain *why* you need that specific version? Forensic study? To replace a corrupt version on an old machine? For a course?

Comment: As said in the recent comment I want to experiment on one of our old softwares but its only usable in windows server 2008 x32 bit edition and when opening requires net framework 4.8 and after a bit of research this is the only possible solution I can get

Comment: @Explorer404 - It's impossible to install .NET Framework 4.8 on Window Server 2008. A 32-bit version of Windows Server 2008 R2 does not exist.

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 SP2 x86 exists in the way back machine so there is a very huge possibility that it is out there in the very corner of the internet and as stated in this article Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0 by microsoft themselves say that it's possible only in the SP1 version of 2008

Comment: @Explorer404 - I will repeat.  It is impossible to install .NET Framework 4.8 on Windows Server 2008 SP1.  Only WS 2008 R2 or newer is supported.

Comment: WS 2008 r2 is it only for x64 or is it for both x64 & x86

Comment: @Explorer404 - I already indicated it’s only 64-bit in a previous comment it’s also easily researched.

Comment: Alright i guess thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To answer my own question yes this is possible only through the waybackmachine using this link: https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://download.microsoft.com/download/b/4/d/b4dc75a1-d7d2-4f31-87f9-e02c950e8d31/6001.18000.080118-1840_x86fre_Server_en-us-KRMSFRE_EN_DVD.iso
using the 2015 timestamp as others are either not working or not found but net framework 4.8 dosen't install as it is unsupported

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Visual Studio subscription or some other Microsoft partner ID, you can download multiple editions of Server 2008 from https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads, along with a license key.

If you don't have any sort of paid Microsoft Subscription, then you may download it from other sources, but its integrity may be compromised.

Comment: No but I require I specific windows server 2008 copy which is SP1 x86 I can't find it on the internet and i might subscribe to it to see if I can get it

Comment: I can see 2008 R2 SP1 but it's only showing x64. The only x86 version is Windows Server 2008 R2 Windows Automated Installation Kit (WAIK)

Comment: So how do I use it? As I want to test an experiment on windows server 2008 but net framework 4.8 is only availible in sp1 version of it

Comment: @Explorer404 - .NET Framework 4.8 cannot be installed on Windows Server 2008. WS2008 and WS2008 R2 are licensed independently. A 32-bit version of WS2008 R2 does not exist. I would be shocked if unsupported copies of Windows Server and Windows were available through the MSDN website.

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 SP2 x86 exists in the way back machine so there is a very huge possibility that it is out there in the very corner of the internet and as stated in this article Link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0 by microsoft themselves say that it's possible only in the SP1 version of 2008

Comment: And as per my research I have found it from the orignal microsoft website it self

Proof: https://imgur.com/a/pThxtkm

Comment: @Explorer404 - This does not change the fact .NET Framework 4.8 still cannot be installed on that version of Windows Server. What exactly does your image prove?

Comment: That sp1 x86 images exist...

Comment: @Explorer404 - That was never in question. Only the legitimacy and integrity of the file you might find. The answers recommendation was to use what essentially is the MSDN subscription to download a licensed copy of WS 2008. My comment suggested that Microsoft does not offer unsupported copies of Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 2003, and Windows 2008 due to their unsupported status. You found an archive link, great, you still cannot install .NET Framework 4.8 on WS 2008. I commented because even if you did find an WS2008 ISO (which you could have simply updated to SP1 through WU) 4.8 is NO-OP

Comment: Well that maybe true but I still needed a copy of it... I'm not some great operating system geek to know all that but I do know some thing with research and as stated in the orignal question i clearly mentioned about windows server 2008 nothing about .net 4.8 untill asked why, but its clear now since I did it. Trying it is better and well to gain experience if I cannot install .net 4.8 then I have to reconsider my options that's all I can say